# Hibernate FETCH.Eager fetching duplicates when using Spring Data repositories

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I am facing an issue with Spring Data repository + Hibernate (in spring `2.1.4`)

**Note:** Everything was working fine in `spring 1.5.x`

The problem is with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)` I get correct records in 1.5 but error in spring 2.0 but with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Eager)` I get duplicate records in `List<Stories>`.

I am using Spring data repositories `epicRepository.findById(Long id)` (previously **Spring** had `epicRepository.find()` but they removed it in spring 2.x)

I don't want to use `@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)` solution as it has to execute multiple select queries and will become very non-performant.

**Problem:**

1. if I use `fetch = FetchType.Lazy` i am getting an error `could not
   initialize proxy - no session` (only started after upgrading to
   spring 2.x and returned correct number of rows) [This error seems to be ok as I am trying to fetch the `list.count` later in the code, and there are no duplicates when I checked through debugger before the erroring line]
2. so based on some solutions here in **SO** I used `FetchType.Eager`
   (I understand the performance implications of this, but anyway I
   needed to do this for another work so I did this because this list is smaller and need to preserve some business logic during updates). But Now I am getting duplicate records.

Even If what I do is wrong, the count in list (mean the duplicates) should not be wrong ?

I have the following `JPA` entities / tables

1. `Epic` ->  [`id` (pk), `name`, `status_id` (fk))
2. `Story`->[`id` (pk), `name`, `status_id` (fk), `epic_id` (fk))
3. `Task` ->  [`id` (pk), `name`, `resolution_type_id` (fk), `story_id` (fk))

forgive me if there any typos (as i recreated code manually using different use case)

**Epic.java**

```
@Data
public class Epic {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.Eager, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = id, referenceColumnName = 'id', nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
  private Status status;
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Eager, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = epic)
  private List<Story> stories;
}
```

**Story.java**

```
@Data
public class Story {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.Eager, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = id, referenceColumnName = 'id', nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
  private Status status;
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Eager, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = epic)
  private List<Task> tasks;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
  // This is the problem area
  // Error if FetchType.Eager 
  // But duplicates in FetchType.Lazy
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false) 
  private Epic epic;
}
```

**Task.java**

```
@Data
public class Task {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private Story story;
  @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.Eager, optional = true)
  @JoinColumn (name = "id", )
  private Resolution resolution;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been replied to many times before. Your options could be:

- all `EAGER` collections you should migrate to `Set`s
- manually do duplicate filtering using `stream.distinct.collect` on getters of collections.

Comment: The question says it  was working fine in spring 1.5.x

Comment: I doubt that EAGER was not supported in earlier Spring version. Or something along that line. This is how Hibernate is intended to work.